# How does CancellationToken work under the hood?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, cancellation-token

Is there another http request that has to be issued?

How does the browser notify the server of abandoned/cancelled request?

Do I need to code my client-side for that to work?

This is my ASP MVC Controller method:

```
[HttpGet("/get")]
public async Task<string> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   //propagate CancellationToken to Entity Framework

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example? The `CancellationToken` is very common and the exact implementation details depends on the actual function you are calling.

Answer (score 4):

1. Browsers can cancel HTTP requests by closing the underlying TCP connection. HTTP.SYS and IIS detect this and pass the connection-closed notification to application code such as ASP.NET. In ASP.NET this is exposed through the `HttpResponse.IsClientConnected` property and other places. See this QA: [Can a http server detect that a client has cancelled their request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652082/can-a-http-server-detect-that-a-client-has-cancelled-their-request)
2. Webpage client scripts cannot cancel a "main" request (a user manually navigating by using the address bar or clicking a link in a page) - only users can cancel that by pressing the Stop button. Your client code can cancel `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX) and modern `fetch` requests by using the `abort()` function (jQuery also exposes this in their own `$.ajax` return object).
3. This article explains how to use `CancellationToken` inside async Controller Action methods: https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/
4. Entity Framework 6 has limited support for async operations, mostly through `ToListAsync` for queries and `SaveChangesAsync` for store operations. Make sure you're using the right extension-methods: [`QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync` does not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220257(v=vs.113).aspx) accept a `CancellationToken` but [`DbRawSqlQuery.ToListAsync` does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176847(v=vs.113).aspx). It should be apparent that `async` is incompatible with EF's Lazy-Loading feature, so you'll need to preemptively load all needed entities in async code so lazy-loading won't be invoked. I recommend disabling Lazy-Loading in most cases anyway.