# Detecting browser closed in middle of a http request response cycle

Tags: java, servlets, browser, tcp, jetty

**Scenario** :

1. Web application connecting to a java servlet. (Using embedded jetty)
2. High latency request, example a report generation ( takes seconds)
3. User can close the browser in between the http request response cycle.

**Problem** :

How to detect browser closed in between the request and response cycle, at the server side ?

Though the problem can be solved by using another request from the UI, I was wondering whether we could get the information from the communication protocol itself ? As HTTP is using TCP/IP as the base protocol, shouldn't we be able to detect this as a connection closed from the connection initiator side.

I went through the servlet apis and also the api used for configuring jetty server but couldn't find anything closely related.

Also went through these stackoverflow questions

1. [Java Servlet : How to detect browser closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299679/java-servlet-how-to-detect-browser-closing)
2. [How to detect browser close at server side in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333152/how-to-detect-browser-close-at-server-side-in-asp-net)

Any insights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get an exception when you attempt to write to the servlet output stream / writer.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Basically you are pointing to the out.checkError() method. I was looking for an event based mechanism, that I can detect **in between** and possibly stop processing.

Comment: I don't think such an event exists but you could fire your own event by listeneing to `window.close()` in the client (javascript) and fire off a second ajax request. Eg: `$(window).close(new function() { ... })`

Comment: the server has no event to trigger from in this situation.  only an attempt to use the connection will cause the event to be noticed.  this can be a read from the request inputstream, or a write to the response outputstream.

Comment: Thank you for the response Joakim. Slowly getting closer to the fact that from java it may not be possible to get the notification of a connection closed from a TCP initiator. I was checking from bottom up, the TCP protocol specifies a handshake (between the initiator and receiver) in this situation. I am currently checking the feasibility of it in a java environment and trying to understand why it is not provided in regular java libraries.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155243/why-is-it-impossible-without-attempting-i-o-to-detect-that-tcp-socket-was-grac do a good job in why it is no possible to detect a connection closed, without communicating. Hard realities :)

Comment: @arunvg and don't forget, Java (and HTTP/0.9, and HTTP/1.0, and HTTP/1.1, and HTTP/2, and Servlets, and WebSocket) support half-closed connections.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt thank you. Can you extend the hint a bit :) . Not able to find anything related to half close connections and servlets. If a client closed event can be detect in between, the design for a resource optimized service provisioning would have much leaner and effective,  than correlating it through another request