# Close the session when client closes

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Servlet : How to detect browser closing ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299679/java-servlet-how-to-detect-browser-closing)

Hi all

I have a question regarding a session timeout, i could not find any answer on the web and all my attempts did not bring any good results.
I would like my session to be closed when the browser closes, i know that the session its in the server and there is not that much to control from the client, but maybe there is something that can be inserted between the:

```
<session-timeout>......</session-timeout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you said : we need a session timeout because there is no reliable way for a server to be notified when a browser closes (or crashes).